# Плохо ли использовать публичные переменные класса?

Tags: c++, code-style

Изучаю С++. Важна скорость. Стоит ли писать методы для одного лишь изменения\получения переменой встроенного типа? Пользовательского типа? Компилятор сообразит? Или пихнуть в паблик и обращаться напрямую?

Во всех "уроках" и книгах для совсем новичков все делают через методы, но непонятно, для наглядности или что бы колено цело было?

Comment: Компилятору пофиг на публичные и приватные переменные -- это ограничение только для программистов и только на уровне синтаксиса языка. И от приватности скорость не изменится. Кроме того, компиляторы умеют отлично код оптимизировать, поэтому не нужно с этим заморачиваться. Когда делаешь get/set поля через метод можно дополнительно сделать какие-нибудь телодвижения (вызывать функцию, изменить еще какое-то поле). Если же нужно только поменять поле класса, то не вижу смысла писать для него дополнительно get и set методы, хотя некоторые считаю это правилом, но это не так. Удачи!

Comment: Я именно это ввиду и имел, падение скорости от вызова методов, вместо прямой записи.

Я очень хотел услышать, что компилятор умеет развертывать get\set до простого запись\чтение памяти.

Comment: Смысл сразу писать get/set в том, чтобы в дальнейшем не понадобилось изменять все места обращения к классу, если встанет задача добавить какие либо действия в момент доступа.

Comment: Если вы только изучаете C++, у вас _нет_ квалификации писать быстрый код. Те «ускорения», которые новички считают ускорениями (отказ от инкапсуляции, например), ускорениями не являются, и у вас ещё даже нет знаний, чтобы понять, почему это так. Ближайшие пять лет не произносите словосочетание «важна скорость».

Comment: Это преждевременная оптимизация. Лучше сосредоточтесь на том, чтобы код был как можно более простым и понятным. Из двух вариантов реализации, один из которых кажется более быстрым, а другой более простым и понятным нужно выбирать простой. А потом, когда программа уже написана и работает, нужно посмотреть, какие именно места неудовлетворяют по скорости и оптимизировать их. Тут то простота и поможет - простой код легко переделать. Сложный и запутанный - тяжело. Заранее предсказать, что именно будет узким местом по производительности практически нереально. Поэтому ранняя оптимизация бессмыленна.

Comment: Все хорошо в меру. Если у вас есть понятие *состояния* объекта, то обеспечить его корректность можно только через инкапсуляцию. Если это просто набор несвязанных данных - смысла в инкапсуляции нет (пример - точка с координатами x и y, которые могут меняться независимо). В производительностью при современных оптимизаторах это связано крайне слабо. Так же, как и пытаться самому руками писать на ассемблере - это только заведомо ухудшить код. А вообще, не там копаете. В очередной раз крайне рекомендую почитать [эту книгу](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это сделано для соблюдения принципа [инкапсуляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) в ООП, т.е. скрытия деталей реализации класса от потребителя класса.

В большинстве случаев, данные класса имеют прямое отношение к конкретным деталям реализации и требуют контроля со стороны разработчика по установке этих данных для соблюдения инвариантов класса. Т.е. значения должны быть установлены таким образом, что бы класс мог корректно работать.

Представь ситуацию, в которой твое поле требует установки не просто любого значения, а конкретных валидных значений (т.е. соблюдения каких-то предусловий). В таких ситуациях отдавать установку значений на откуп пользователя твоего класса было бы опрометчиво:

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    int _width;
    int _height;

public:
    void setWidth(int width)
    {
        if (width > 0)
           _width = width;

        ...
    }
};
```

В данном примере, установка ширины прямоугольника и проверка предусловий (ширина не может быть нулевой или отрицательной) и, как следствие, соблюдения инварианта класса (не может быть прямоугольника с отрицательной или нулевой шириной) прямая обязанность класса Rectangle, так как пользователь может ничего не знать о внутреннем устройстве вашего класса и устанавливать любые значения, в том числе некорректные.

Comment: Да, я понял вас.

Comment: Добавлю еще, что если в какой-то момент автор этого класса решит задавать его при помощи двух точек, то ему не придется исправлять 100500 мест в коде, где использовалась высота. Он просто перепишет методы `width` и `setWidth`

Answer (score 1):

Это сделано не только из соблюдения принципа инкапсуляции. Допустим, у вас класс Прямоугольник с его параметрами x₁, y₁, x₂, y₂. Если объекты сперва создаются, а только потом используются без изменений (такое бывает часто), нет проблем, можете присвоить значения свойствам напрямую. В относительно новом языке TypeScript, если я ничего не путаю, свойства даже могут задаваться в интерфейсах. ООП же подразумевает задачи со сложными связями между объектами. Это значит, например, что ваш прямоугольник уже нарисован где-то в объекте класса Полотно. Что даст простое изменение свойства? Ничего. Прямоугольник должен быть перерисован при изменении свойства.